# Git status summary by file extension

Tags: git

Is there a possibility to change the output of `git status`, so that is shows only one line per file extension? e.g,

```
M *.java -> 12
D *.html -> 2
M *.md -> 1
```

I am on Unix, so some grep magic would do as well.

Comment: You can `git status | grep .java | echo "java" \`wc -l\``. Of course this should be modified and improved to group all similar extensions, but maybe it's the direction.

Comment: `git status --porcelain` and see https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_short_format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
git status -s | awk '{print $2}' \
    | sed -e 's/.*\(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\)$/\1/' \
    | uniq -c
```

Where:

`awk '{print $2}'` - match updated files

`sed -e 's/.*\(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\)$/\1/'` - extract file extension

`uniq -c` - calcalate count

Comment: Can I get the initial identifier als well? E.g., `M, A, D` (first letter of line).

Comment: @kerner1000: there are *two* letters in the first two columns (then a space, then the file name). The first is from comparing HEAD vs index, the second is from comparing index vs work-tree. Consider what you want for, e.g., `AM` vs `MM`. Then, what do you want for one .html that's added and several more than are modified?

Comment: hmm, i have only one. `$ git status -s
 M [..].java`

Comment: @kerner1000 Actually you must see http://storage1.static.itmages.com/i/17/0814/h_1502731940_5612922_663bd9f782.png it is 2 column output, but `M` present in one of them.

Comment: Ah, you are right! Was never aware of that, thanks! Can you modify your answer to include maybe both (if present) letters?

Comment: @kerner1000 But it works regardless of this letters, it matches files names on first stage and don't consider this characters.

Comment: @kerner1000 Here output for my case http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1502734617.png

Answer (score 0):

The better is to add sort, because files can be in different folders

```
git status -s | awk '{print $2}'     \
          | sed -e 's/.*\(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\)$/\1/'  \
          | sort   \
          | uniq -c
```